# MySQL Docker Container INFILE/ INTO OUTFILE statement on MacOS System

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I hava a Java program and a mysql Docker container (image: mysql:5.7.20).
My MacOs is High Sierra 10.13.4.

**The problem in short**

Using Docker on MacOS (10.13.4.). Inside a docker container (image: mysql:5.7.20) mostly the queries (executed from a java program)

- `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`
- `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`

are working fine, but sometimes the java program throws the exceptions:

- SQLException: Can't create/write to file ‘…’ (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
- SQLException: Can't get stat of ‘…’ Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
- SQLException: The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
- SQLException: File ‘…’ not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

btw. the file exists and the permissions should be fine (see longer version)

**The longer version**

The process is the following:

- a .csv file gets created
- this .csv file is copied into a directory, which is mounted for the docker container

  - docker-compose volumes section: `- "./data/datahub/import:/var/lib/mysql-files/datahub/import"`
- then MySQL reads this .csv file into a table:

  - `LOAD DATA INFILE '.csv-file' REPLACE INTO TABLE 'my-table';`
- then some stuff on that database happens
- after that MySQL writes an .csv output file

  - `SELECT`tbl`.`sku`,`tbl`.`deleted`,`tbl`.`data_source_values`INTO OUTFILE 'output.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' FROM (SELECT ...`

This project has some java integration-tests for this process. These tests are mostly green, but sometimes they fail with:

- SQLException: Can't create/write to file ‘…’ (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
- SQLException: Can't get stat of ‘…’ Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
- SQLException: The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
- SQLException: File ‘…’ not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

The docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    datahub_db:
      image: "mysql:5.7.20"
      restart: always
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATAHUB_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATAHUB_DB_DATABASE}
      volumes:
        - "datahub_db:/var/lib/mysql"
        - "./data/datahub/import:/var/lib/mysql-files/datahub/import"
        - "./data/akeneo/import:/var/lib/mysql-files/akeneo/import"
      ports:
        - "${DATAHUB_DB_PORT}:3306"

...

volumes:
  datahub_db:
```

The Log from that Docker database container shows the following (but sometimes, this happened when all test are green, too)

- `datahub_db_1  | 2018-06-01T10:04:33.937646Z 144 [Note] Aborted connection 144 to db: 'datahub_test' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

The .csv file inside the datahub container, shows the following, fo `ls -lha`

```
root@e02e2074fb6b:/var/lib/mysql- 
files/datahub/import/test/products/kaw# ls -lha
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  96 Jun  1 09:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  96 Jun  1 09:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 378 Jun  1 06:47 deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv
```

I think there is no problem, that this file belongs to root because mostly this file can get read by MySQL. When I change to user `mysql` via `su mysql` inside the Docker container, I get the following:

```
$ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 mysql mysql  96 Jun  1 09:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 mysql mysql  96 Jun  1 09:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 378 Jun  1 06:47 deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv
```

Now some strange stuff happened.

- with root user, i could make a `cat deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv`
- with mysql user i couldn't i got:

Output:

```
$ cat deactivated_product_merge_bub.csv
cat: deactivated_product_merge_bub.csv: No such file or directory
```

I made a `stat deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv` as MySQL user and suddenly I could make a `cat` on that file (as you see I `chmod 777` to that file to get the `cat` working - but it didn't work).

- `stat` as root

Output:

```
root@e02e2074fb6b:/var/lib/mysql-files/datahub/import/test/products/kaw# stat 
deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv 
  File: 'deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv'
  Size: 378         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
Device: 4fh/79d Inode: 4112125     Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-06-01 09:23:38.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2018-06-01 06:47:44.000000000 +0000
Change: 2018-06-01 09:04:53.000000000 +0000
  Birth: -
```

- `stat` as mysql user

Output:

```
$ stat deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv
  File: 'deactivated_product_merged_bub.csv'
  Size: 378         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
Device: 4fh/79d Inode: 4112125     Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  999/   mysql)   Gid: (  999/   mysql)
Access: 2018-06-01 09:32:25.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2018-06-01 06:47:44.000000000 +0000
Change: 2018-06-01 09:04:53.000000000 +0000
  Birth: -
```

**Question**

Does anyone knows, what happened here or has a hint for what I could search to dig deeper?

My speculation is that it's because using Docker with MacOs and the mounted volume.

Comment: Instead of `su mysql`, try `sudo mysql bash` (or your favorite shell).

Comment: Do you use ACLs or another access control mechanism, except discrete?

Comment: ACLs are used by the Linux developer, the macOS and Windows developer doesn't use ACLs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're likely running into two separate problems here, both related to configuration of the MySQL server.

> The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it
>   cannot execute this statement.

This option requires any file loading or file export to be placed in the specified storage location in the file system.
You can find the location using the following command from either the MySQL command line client or from MySQL Workbench:

```
mysql> show variables like 'secure-file-priv';
```

The result from this should identify the location where files can be loaded and written out to. No other location should be allowed when secure-file-priv is enabled.

> (Got an error reading communication packets)

This is often caused by data being loaded or exported which exceeds the MySQL variable max-allowed-packet.

You can similarly find the value for max-allowed-packet using the following command from either the MySQL command line client or from MySQL Workbench:

```
mysql> show variables like 'max-allowed-packet';
```

This has been addressed and well answered in this question:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets

In summation:
In /etc/my.cnf or my.ini under the [mysqld] section:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=268435456
```

‬In the running MySQL instance:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 268435456;
```

(No restart of the service is required.)

As an aside, the MySQL account that you're using must have been granted the 'FILE' permission in order to load or export. Since you're using the MySQL root (administrative) account this should not be a factor, but I thought I would include it for anyone who comes across this.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that you are trying to access a file who is outside the default shared paths of docker for mac (from the docker osx documentation)

> By default, you can share files in /Users/, /Volumes/, /private/, and
> /tmp directly. To add or remove directory trees that are exported to
> Docker, use the File sharing tab in Docker preferences whale menu ->
> Preferences -> File sharing. (See Preferences.)
>
> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces

In the case, docker for mac is using a linux virtual machine run by hyperkit on Mac OS. The client run on macOSx and the daemon in the VM. That explain you have to share files in a restricted list of paths.

Comment: Thx for your answer. UnfortunatelyI can't verify the answer (anymore), cause I don't work for the company anymore. I didn't take that code home with me. Perhaps someone else could verify it, and I will mark this question solved.

Edit: But I assume that's not the problem, because in the docker-compose file, I define the paths where the files can be found (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @SleepyX667 yes but the docker-compose file is parsed by your VM which can't access those paths if you don't share them explicitly through the docker client config on macOSX. On MacOSX go to the Docker tray icon > Preferences > File Sharing to convince yourself. Mine is only sharing /Users /Volumes /private.

Comment: i understand, but if the vm wouldn't have access then the problem would be all the time, or? But i got these exceptions only sometimes.

Comment: Ok i didn't get that right sorry. Usualy this error message is about length of the data parsed. Does the file differs from 2 runs, one succesfull the other one failling ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with permission to share folders between docker containers and host. You need to map containers' users with host's users by setting UID in .env file.

```
UID=501 # run echo $UID to get current user id
```

```
version: '3'
  services:
    datahub_db:
      image: "mysql:5.7.20"
      user: $UID
      restart: always
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATAHUB_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATAHUB_DB_DATABASE}
      volumes:
        - "datahub_db:/var/lib/mysql"
        - "./data/datahub/import:/var/lib/mysql-files/datahub/import"
        - "./data/akeneo/import:/var/lib/mysql-files/akeneo/import"
      ports:
        - "${DATAHUB_DB_PORT}:3306"

...

volumes:
  datahub_db:
```